# Error while generating a new service using "DB Connect" in Apigility

Tags: php, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

In Apigility admin I'm trying to generate a new service using the "DB Connected" option, but after load all tables of database, I choose one and click in "Create Service". I get a error in console as displayed in image bellow:

[image]
Logs:

```
[Error] Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.rest.table_name')
ok@http://localhost:8888/apigility-ui/c22d22af.apigility.js:1:11687
http://localhost:8888/apigility-ui/6a8334db.vendor.js:6:18549
e@http://localhost:8888/apigility-ui/6a8334db.vendor.js:6:25924
$eval@http://localhost:8888/apigility-ui/6a8334db.vendor.js:5:34068
$apply@http://localhost:8888/apigility-ui/6a8334db.vendor.js:5:34351
http://localhost:8888/apigility-ui/6a8334db.vendor.js:6:25981
dispatch@http://localhost:8888/apigility-ui/6a8334db.vendor.js:2:14429
handle@http://localhost:8888/apigility-ui/6a8334db.vendor.js:2:11204
    (anonymous function) (6a8334db.vendor.js, line 5)
    (anonymous function) (6a8334db.vendor.js, line 4)
    $apply (6a8334db.vendor.js, line 5)
    (anonymous function) (6a8334db.vendor.js, line 6)
    dispatch (6a8334db.vendor.js, line 2)
    handle (6a8334db.vendor.js, line 2)
```

The service is not created.

Someone knows how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now it is possible use dev-master for resolve this issue while version 1.3.2 is not released. Just add the line `"zfcampus/zf-apigility-admin-ui": "dev-master"`, in section "require-dev" in your project's composer.json. Reference: github.com/zfcampus/zf-apigility-admin/issues/307